# Hapi 17 Stripe intermittent failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, hapi.js

I am completely baffled. I have a pay route, that allows people to pay through paypal, or stripe. Depending on their location, they will pay in USD or GBP / EUR.

I have two stripe gateways, one for US, the other for UK/EU.

The payment form is 'as-is' Stripe Checkout and dropped onto the front end.

Most of the time, I am able to make payment without any issue - switching between the US and UK without any problems.

However, occasionally I receive the following error message:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: stripe is not a function
```

pointing to the line in my stripe.js file, where I set stripe up with the secret key. I'm confused, because it works most of the time - and is a method.

I refresh the browser and it seems to be ok, to then break later.

pay.js

```
    const stripeMethods = require("./../../utilities/stripe.js");
    const braintreeMethods = require("./../../utilities/braintree.js");

    module.exports = {
        method: ["POST"],
        path: "/pay/{task}",
        options: {
            // ... validations, removed
            async handler(request, h) {

                let cart = request.session.cart;
                let orderid = await request.getUniqueToken(8, 'order', 'orderid'); // generate order id
                let charge;

                switch (request.params.task) {
                    case "stripe":
                        charge = await stripeMethods.charge(request.payload.token, cart, orderid);
                        cart.paymentType = 'stripe';
                        break;
                    case "paypal":
                        charge = await braintreeMethods.charge(request.payload.token, cart, orderid);
                        cart.paymentType = 'paypal';
                        break;
                }
                // .... do a bunch of stuff with createOrder - removed
            }
        }
    };
```

stripe.js contains the following:

```
 <!-- language: lang-js -->

let stripe = require('stripe');

const charge = async (token, cart, orderid) => {

    try {
        if (cart.total.currency === 'GBP' || cart.total.currency === 'EUR') {
            stripe = stripe('###########'); // secret for UK Stripe, hardwired in for testing
        } else {
            stripe = stripe('##########'); // secret for USA Stripe
        }
        let charge = await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: Math.trunc(cart.total.total), // truncates without rounding
            currency: cart.total.currency,
            source: token, // obtained with Stripe.js
            description: `....`
        });
```

And, intermittently, I get the following error... Stripe is not a function. It seems to happen randomly (of course, I know it isn't random.. I've just yet to be able to identify a pattern).

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: stripe is not a function
    at Object.charge (.../utilities/stripe.js:8:18)
    at handler (.../web/routes/pay.js:51:50)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

I'm running a method inside the 'onPostAuth' handler to detect for the presence of a cart.

In theory, it should only run when there is no cart. So when a customer first lands on the site, and when a customer checks out (the cart gets wiped, and is reinitialised)

```
   if (request.session && !request.session.cart) {
        console.log('RUNNING WHEN PATH?', request.path)
        request.session.cart = cartMethods.cartSetup(); // if no cart - set one up
    }
```

I'm logging out the path where the cart reports as missing. It appears to run when css.map files are hit.. (the cart page is a vue.js app - the checkout is just a page of html

I think in the first instance, I should amend my onPostAuth to ignore anything with .map in the path

** EDIT **

Following on from @karllekko's comment - I required both my UK and USA at the head of the file - and referenced those variables inside my method.

```
let ukStripe = require('stripe'('sk_test_#######################');
let usStripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_#######################');

const charge = async (token, cart, orderid) => {
    try {
        let stripe;
        if (cart.total.currency === 'GBP' || cart.total.currency === 'EUR') {
            stripe = ukStripe;
        } else {
            stripe = usStripe;
        }
```

This is working - making payment after payment without fail. However, its bugging me... really bugging me. I can't figure out why this is working. The scope shouldn't have been an issue... if anyone can share any insights, that would be great. I've googled - but not found any answers as to why.

** Edit **

Spoke with my pal Dave - its now incredibly obvious... I'm kicking myself...

Dave [9:52 AM]
it's pretty obvious
you're reassigning `stripe` every time
`stripe = stripe('###########')`

rob [9:52 AM]
....Oh crap.... you're right

Dave [9:52 AM]
`stripe = _return value of stripe()_`

Dave [9:52 AM]
tip: never use `let`
always use `const`
that way, if you do this by accident, you can see where

rob [9:53 AM]
:+1: const refers to the type doesnt it?

Dave [9:53 AM]
no

rob [9:53 AM]
(unless its a string - then the value)

Dave [9:53 AM]
`const` prevents reassigning an identifier
if that value is an object then sure you can change the object contents, but yea a string can't be modified
primitives vs objects

---- so the problem was me.

Comment: To clarify, you're using [stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)? Which version? Also, instead of re-initializing the Stripe library with a different key each time, you could instead `require` it twice to have two instances and use those? Not sure if that would help but you could try it. i.e `let ukStripe = require('stripe')("sk_test_uk); let usaStripe = require('stripe')("sk_test_usa);`

Comment: Thanks - the lates - 6.3.0. and I will try now what you suggest with the require. Thanks!

Comment: @karllekko - that little trick seems to have worked... requiring, and then referencing the variable seems to have worked!! The last 10 orders went through without any problems. I have burned a day over this - thankyou!!! thankyou!!!